# Can't figure out hexadecimal conversion with pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, hex, decimal, atoi

So I am getting pretty frustrated with this and feel the only way to figure out exactly what I am doing wrong is to ask you fine people. I am trying to convert a string of characters (contains number values) to hexadecimal. Here is my code (note, I haven't placed the switch for 10-15 to letters yet; I just wanted to make sure I was getting back integer values when I ran this... no luck):

```
void toHex(char *inString){
    char *charVal = inString;
    char decVal[100];

    for(int i = 0; decVal[i] != '\0'; i++){
        decVal[i] = *charVal;
        charVal++;
    }

    char storeMod[100];
    int i = 0;
    int testVal = atoi(decVal);

    for(i; testVal >= 16; i++){
        int a = testVal;
        testVal = testVal/16;
        storeMod[i] = a;
    }

   int a = 0;
   char hexval[100];
   hexVal[0] = '0';
   hexVal[1] = 'x';
   for(int j = i+2; j>=2; j--){
       hexVal[j] = storeMod[a];
       a++;
   }

   printf("%s hex valu\n", hexVal);
   return;
}
```

For example, an input of 300 returns ,@

I have also tried:

```
char hexVal[100];
sprintf(hexVal,"%x",*inString);
strcpy(instring,hexVal);
```

which returns a hex value of 3fa844e0 for 300 which is obviously wrong as well. Any help is appreciated, I need to do this for octals too so I have to figure this concept out and see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: For style and clarity, I'd recommend replacing the first loop in `toHex` with a call to `strcpy`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
sprintf(hexVal,"%x",*inString);
```

Use:

```
sprintf(hexVal, "%x", atoi(inString));
```

Comment: Depending on the length of `inString`, you may need to use `atol()` instead of `atoi()`.

Comment: @AdamLiss Yes that is true. This will work for the test case of 300, but not for arbitrary length strings.

Comment: If you use `atol`, remember to use `"%lx"`

Comment: Thank you for the help, however when I run it as corrected it returns random 8 character strings (eg f8a325ac). When I input printf("%d",atoi(inString)); to test it returns 300 as its value, but it isn't returning the proper value after sprintf is run. Could it be that I have the buffers set too large (they aren't too small)?

Comment: @ZachCaudle Is that (f8a325ac) the output of `printf("%s", hexVal);`?

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. I am going to punch myself in the face. I was doing printf("%x", hexVal); ... and with that, solid proof I need to go to bed. Thank you very much for the help everyone

Comment: @ZachCaudle Haha, I always like the surprise rep when someone learns about accepting answers :) Thanks

Comment: Haha sorry it took me so long. Should have called me out

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, you can replace your whole function with:

```
printf("%lx\n", strtol(inString, NULL, 10));
```

But, if this is for school or personal gratification, you seem to know the two main steps.

- Convert the string to an integer
- Encode the integer back into a string of the right base.

For step one, step through the number left-to-right (which is easy in a string) multiplying a running result by 10, and adding the current digit.

For step two, simply run through the number four bits(one hex digit) at a time, inserting that plus `'0'`. If you've started from the LSB, remember to reverse the string.